# How to combine 3 loop functions into 1 function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, pandas-styles

This is the example data/script I am working with. If possible, I am trying to make fewer lines of code on the last part so it looks more clean/efficient. As you can see, the block below :

```
    styler=(df.style
              .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
    )
    dfi.export(styler, f'test1_{i}.png')
```

is repeating two more times with different list names, `df_list2` and `df_list3`. How can I combine three loop functions into one loop function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import dataframe_image as dfi

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[-100,500,400,0,222,222], [9000,124,0,-147,54,-56],[77,0,110,211,0,222], [111,11,-600,33,0,22],[213,-124,0,-147,54,-56]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[100,500,200,0,555,222], [5000,124,0,-147,54,50],[77,0,500,211,0,222], [-900,11,-600,33,0,22],[500,-124,0,-147,54,-56]])

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x','y','z'], list('ab')])
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x','y','z'], list('ab')])

df_list1=[df]
df_list2=[df2]
df_list3=[df,df2]


def colors(i):
    if i < 0:
        return 'background: red'
    elif i > 0:
        return 'background: green'
    elif i == 0:
        return 'background: yellow'
    else:
        ''

for i, df in enumerate(df_list1):
    styler=(df.style
              .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
    )
    dfi.export(styler, f'test1_{i}.png')
    
for i, df in enumerate(df_list2):
    styler=(df.style
              .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
    )
    dfi.export(styler, f'test2_{i}.png')
    
for i, df in enumerate(df_list3):
    styler=(df.style
              .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
    )
    dfi.export(styler, f'test3_{i}.png')
```

Comment: A bit unusual to see `Positive` values in `RED` and `Negative` values in `GREEN`. I assume you have your reasons, however, I believe this breaks colour theory :)

Comment: Hey ScottC, yeah sorry I just made it up for the purpose of creating a sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another loop by list `L`, also use `enumerate(L, 1)` for count from `1`, last change generate name of `png` with `j` variable:

```
L = [df_list1, df_list2, df_list3]


for j, df_list in enumerate(L, 1):
    for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
        styler=(df.style
                  .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
        )
        dfi.export(styler, f'test{j}_{i}.png')
```

EDIT: You can zip new list:

```
L = [df_list1, df_list2, df_list3]
names = ['math', 'biology', 'music']

out = zip(names, L)

for j, (name, df_list) in enumerate(out, 1):
    for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
        styler=(df.style
                  .applymap(colors, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:,'a']])
        )
        dfi.export(styler,f'{name}_{i}.png')
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, this works perfectly! Thanks as always. Is it possible to assign different names for each list, instead of 'test'? So for example, df_list1 with math{i}, df_list2 with biology{i}, and df_list3 with music{i}?

Comment: You could have your names in a list (strings) and apply the same logic  ie. `f'{names[j]}{j}_{i}.png'` where `names = ['math', 'biology', 'music']`

Comment: You mean like creating a dictionary and wrapping it around? for example,```file_names = {0: 'math', 1: 'biology', 2:'Diabetes', 3:'music'}  f'test{file_names[i]})``` something like this?

Comment: @yeppi - Answer was edited, can you test? Btw, last column solution working well in my opinion

Comment: Thanks so much, jezrael! I may have to post another question to clarify what is being asked. Your answer already provided so much insight.